# Angular2 radio button not working in Production

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I recenlty built an angular2 application using Visual Studio 2015 and MVC. The project also hosts WEBAPI along with angular code. I integrated MS Build with Angular build using the instructions shown here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1193423/Integrating-the-Angular-CLI-With-Visual-Studio

I am also using WEBPACK to minify files during build.

The issue i am having is with radio buttons. My application has bunch of radio buttons and onclick i have to clear some textboxes. The below code works fine on my machine when i run in DEBUG mode.

```
<input type="radio" value="option1" [(ngModel)]="planCtrl.ctrlVal" name="RdnBtn_PlanTesting"       (click)="TxtBx2_PlanTesting=''" required>
```

But when i deploy it to production 'click' event never fires. It fires only after i remove the '[(ngModel)]' piece. After some research when i change the 'click' method to 'ngModelChange' it started working.

```
 <input type="radio" value="option1" [(ngModel)]="planCtrl.ctrlVal"
     name="RdnBtn_PlanTesting"      
     (ngModelChange)="TxtBx2_PlanTesting=''" required>
```

In debug mode i am using "ng build" command.
In release mode i am using "ng build --prod" command.

I want to understand what is causing the issue in production. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?