# Angular2+ (click) event on radio button not working on Safari/iOS

Tags: html, angular, safari

The page is working perfectly in Chrome, IE or Firefox, but in Safari I have a weird problem. The (click) events that are inside the radio buttons are not working, the event is not fired. I have another (click) in a button later and it works fine. The problem happens on iPhone/iMac so is not device related.

The page is nothing more than a survey with some questions. Here is an example of html code:

```
<div class="col" *ngIf="!valueSelection">
    <h4 for="">1.- Question 1</h4>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="questionRMG1" id="questionRMG1_1" value="answerRMG1_1" [(ngModel)]="valueSelection"
         (click)="onSelect(0.25)">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="questionRMG1_1">Answer a.</label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="questionRMG1" id="questionRMG1_2" value="answerRMG1_2" [(ngModel)]="valueSelection"
         (click)="onSelect(0.10)">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="questionRMG1_2">Answer b./label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="questionRMG1" id="questionRMG1_3" value="answerRMG1_3" [(ngModel)]="valueSelection"
         (click)="onSelect(0)">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="questionRMG1_3">Answer c. </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="questionRMG1" id="questionRMG1_4" value="answerRMG1_4" [(ngModel)]="valueSelection"
         (click)="onSelect(0,50)">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="questionRMG1_4">Answer d. </label>
    </div>
    <p>
        <ngb-progressbar [value]="0" type="info">0%</ngb-progressbar>
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is the code of the (click) that works fine:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h4>Text</h4>
            <br>
            <form #mailForm="ngForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputName1">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" [(ngModel)]="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="nombre empresa">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Mail</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" [(ngModel)]="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                     placeholder="mail">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Text</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" [(ngModel)]="inputCheck" name="inputCheck">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSend()" ng-disabled="sending">Enviar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I really have no idea of what the problem could be.

Comment: Well the problem is Safari obviously ... Consider stop using Apple products ? Jokes apart, could you test if vanilla `onclick` events work ?

Comment: Sorry if i didnt explain myself correctly, both fragments of code are part of the same page, the survey only shows one question at a time, when it ends it shows the code with the (click) that works, so (click) is working outside the radio buttons.

Comment: This was clear, I'm asking if `onclick` events are triggered on radio buttons. Could you test that ?

Comment: When clicking on the radio buttons the survey goes to the next question, that works fine. Is that what you are asking for?, sorry again if i misunderstand you.

Comment: No it's not. In javascript, you can bind events to HTML elements : in Angular you write `(click)="function()"`, in native JS it is `onclick="function()"`. I am asking you to test if click events work on your radio buttons in native javascript. If they don't then it means Safari can't bind click events to buttons. But if it does, it means Angular has an issue with Safari and radio click events. I'm trying to spot the issue, so that I can offer you an adapted answer.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation,  i tried changing (click)="onSelect()"   with onclick="onSelect()", but it doesn´t work in any browser (Chrome, Firefox or Safari). :(

Comment: In your console, do you see a `Error: unknown function 'onSelect'` or close to that ? Or nothing at all ?

Comment: Yes, this is the error code: Uncaught ReferenceError: onSelect is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (formmatriz:1)

Comment: Okay so your issue is with Angular. Did you try binding to `(change)` instead of `(click)` ?

Comment: I just tried (change) instead of (click), in Chrome/Firefox it works fine, in Safari nothing, the event is not triggered, same as with (click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research, i found a similar question: [Angular2 radio button not working in Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492505/angular2-radio-button-not-working-in-production)

I tried changing the environment production variable to false, and now everything works on Safari.

It´s a solution, but i don´t understand why this happens, doesn´t make sense.